# Proper way to distribute web.config as a third party web service provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I was wondering what's the best way to distribute the web.config when it's part of a web service that's meant to be installed by an installer on any machines.  In my situation the web.config contains http handlers that's required by the web service to function properly, but once installed the user can change options from within IIS for the web service and this will change the web.config (e.g. authorization, connection string, etc.).  The issue is if I make the web.config part of the installation/upgrade if will override all user defined settings but if I don't it might be missing new https handlers or other critical new web.config settings.  What's the best practice regarding web.config distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a little on what exactly your service needs to use in web.config.

You can use the [ConfigSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource(v=vs.110).aspx) property on certain sections in web.config to move **all** settings in that section to an external secondary file.

For example:

```
<system.webServer><handlers ConfigSource="httphandlers.config" />
```

You can then update the httphandlers.config yourself without fearing the customer making any modifications to it.

The problem arises if your customers need to add their own http handlers, then you have the same problem as before.

You shouldn't put a `ConfigSource` on `<appSettings>`, but define your own `configSection`, and then put that section into a secondary file as well. All the settings related to your service should go in there.

So as long as you don't share a section with your customers, this should work.

This is just the concept, I don't use this in production myself.

Comment: I never realized that you could break out the http handlers in another .config file, this might solve our issue as this is where we had issues in the past (they were not updated as we didn't update the new web.config because we were afraid to overwrite user settings).  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question, I am not sure if I have ever come across a best practice guide for this.  It's very similar to the user changing an installed DLL to their custom one and then upgrading the application.  As long as the MSI database has a record of that DLL, the custom DLL will get replaced.

My recommendation would be to have a post install action (most installers e.g. WIX allow you do these in C#) which would do the following:

1. Fresh install, post action copies Web.Install.Config to Web.config
2. User can modify the web.config to their hearts content
3. Upgrade, post action is clever enough to know that a web.config exists and merges the settings

Several problems you need to worry about:

1. Obviously merging settings is always fun (NOT :))
2. What if you have actually changed an existing setting in the config file to a better value (e.g. timeout), does your change win or the customers change?
3. What if they actually delete a setting entirely? Will you readd it?

There are several other questions which will drive your design, to be honest I don't think this forum will get you anywhere close to a solution that will fit all your needs.

I would love to see what you end up with though.

Comment: We might go with what Peter mentioned as the http handlers were our major problems, I never realized that certain sections could be broken out in separate .config.  This new config will always update, as opposed as the web.config we will probably just install it on the first install.

Comment: Very true although there's nothing stopping the user from modifying those files either, just FYI :)

Comment: Yes I do realize that that its' possible, but not very much and it reduces the conflicts a lot as no user settings would be be stored in a config file specifically for http handlers and it would not make sense for them to add or remove http handlers for our self contained web app (which is only a middle tier for a mobile application).